# I am getting error while importing Policymanager?

Tags: android-widget

I am writing code for my own media-controller for VideoView.
and my code is as follows

```
public class FMediaController extends FrameLayout {

private MediaPlayerControl  mPlayer;
private Context             mContext;
private View                mAnchor;
private View                mRoot;
private WindowManager       mWindowManager;
private Window              mWindow;
private View                mDecor;
private ProgressBar         mProgress;
private TextView            mEndTime, mCurrentTime;
private boolean             mShowing;
private boolean             mDragging;
private static final int    sDefaultTimeout = 3000;
private static final int    FADE_OUT = 1;
private static final int    SHOW_PROGRESS = 2;
private boolean             mUseFastForward;
private boolean             mFromXml;
private boolean             mListenersSet;
private View.OnClickListener mNextListener, mPrevListener;
StringBuilder               mFormatBuilder;
Formatter                   mFormatter;
private ImageButton         mPauseButton;
private ImageButton         mFfwdButton;
private ImageButton         mRewButton;
private ImageButton         mNextButton;
private ImageButton         mPrevButton;

public FMediaController(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mRoot = this;
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = true;
    mFromXml = true;
}

@Override
public void onFinishInflate() {
    if (mRoot != null)
        initControllerView(mRoot);
}

public FMediaController(Context context, boolean useFastForward) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = useFastForward;
    initFloatingWindow();
}

public FMediaController(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mUseFastForward = true;
    initFloatingWindow();
}

private void initFloatingWindow() {
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService("window");
   mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);
    mWindow.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);
    mWindow.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDecor = mWindow.getDecorView();
    mDecor.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    mWindow.setContentView(this);
    mWindow.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    // While the media controller is up, the volume control keys should
    // affect the media stream type
    mWindow.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
    requestFocus();
}

private OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (mShowing) {
                hide();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

public void setMediaPlayer(MediaPlayerControl player) {
    mPlayer = player;
    updatePausePlay();
}

/**
 * Set the view that acts as the anchor for the control view.
 * This can for example be a VideoView, or your Activity's main view.
 * @param view The view to which to anchor the controller when it is visible.
 */
public void setAnchorView(View view) {
    mAnchor = view;

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
    );

    removeAllViews();
    View v = makeControllerView();
    addView(v, frameParams);
}

/**
 * Create the view that holds the widgets that control playback.
 * Derived classes can override this to create their own.
 * @return The controller view.
 * @hide This doesn't work as advertised
 */
protected View makeControllerView() {
    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mRoot = inflate.inflate(R.layout.media_controller, null);

    initControllerView(mRoot);

    return mRoot;
}

private void initControllerView(View v) {
    mPauseButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.requestFocus();
        mPauseButton.setOnClickListener(mPauseListener);
    }

    mFfwdButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ffwd);
    if (mFfwdButton != null) {
        mFfwdButton.setOnClickListener(mFfwdListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mFfwdButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    mRewButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rew);
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setOnClickListener(mRewListener);
        if (!mFromXml) {
            mRewButton.setVisibility(mUseFastForward ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // By default these are hidden. They will be enabled when setPrevNextListeners() is called 
    mNextButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
    if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        mNextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    mPrevButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.prev);
    if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
        mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.mediacontroller_progress);
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (mProgress instanceof SeekBar) {
            SeekBar seeker = (SeekBar) mProgress;
            seeker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(mSeekListener);
        }
        mProgress.setMax(1000);
    }

    mEndTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    mCurrentTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time_current);
    mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

    installPrevNextListeners();
}

/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 3 seconds of inactivity.
 */
public void show() {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
}

/**
 * Show the controller on screen. It will go away
 * automatically after 'timeout' milliseconds of inactivity.
 * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. Use 0 to show
 * the controller until hide() is called.
 */
public void show(int timeout) {

    if (!mShowing && mAnchor != null) {
        setProgress();

        int [] anchorpos = new int[2];
        mAnchor.getLocationOnScreen(anchorpos);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        p.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        p.width = mAnchor.getWidth();
        p.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        p.x = 0;
        p.y = anchorpos[1] + mAnchor.getHeight() - p.height;
        p.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        p.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL;
        p.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;
        p.token = null;
        p.windowAnimations = 0; // android.R.style.DropDownAnimationDown;
        mWindowManager.addView(mDecor, p);
        mShowing = true;
    }
    updatePausePlay();

    // cause the progress bar to be updated even if mShowing
    // was already true.  This happens, for example, if we're
    // paused with the progress bar showing the user hits play.
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);

    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(FADE_OUT);
    if (timeout != 0) {
        mHandler.removeMessages(FADE_OUT);
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg, timeout);
    }
}

public boolean isShowing() {
    return mShowing;
}

/**
 * Remove the controller from the screen.
 */
public void hide() {
    if (mAnchor == null)
        return;

    if (mShowing) {
        try {
            mHandler.removeMessages(SHOW_PROGRESS);
            mWindowManager.removeView(mDecor);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.w("MediaController", "already removed");
        }
        mShowing = false;
    }
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int pos;
        switch (msg.what) {
            case FADE_OUT:
                hide();
                break;
            case SHOW_PROGRESS:
                pos = setProgress();
                if (!mDragging && mShowing && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    msg = obtainMessage(SHOW_PROGRESS);
                    sendMessageDelayed(msg, 1000 - (pos % 1000));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
};

private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
    int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

    int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
    int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
    int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

    mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
    if (hours > 0) {
        return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
    } else {
        return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
    }
}

private int setProgress() {
    if (mPlayer == null || mDragging) {
        return 0;
    }
    int position = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    int duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
    if (mProgress != null) {
        if (duration > 0) {
            // use long to avoid overflow
            long pos = 1000L * position / duration;
            mProgress.setProgress( (int) pos);
        }
        int percent = mPlayer.getBufferPercentage();
        mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent * 10);
    }

    if (mEndTime != null)
        mEndTime.setText(stringForTime(duration));
    if (mCurrentTime != null)
        mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime(position));

    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    show(sDefaultTimeout);
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && event.isLongPress() && (
            keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK ||
            keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE ||
            keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE)) {
        doPauseResume();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode ==  KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP) {
        if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.pause();
            updatePausePlay();
        }
        return true;
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ||
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        // don't show the controls for volume adjustment
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        hide();

        return true;
    } else {
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}

private View.OnClickListener mPauseListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doPauseResume();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private void updatePausePlay() {
    if (mRoot == null)
        return;

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) mRoot.findViewById(R.id.pause);
    if (button == null)
        return;

    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        button.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
    } else {
        button.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
    }
}

private void doPauseResume() {
    if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    updatePausePlay();
}

private OnSeekBarChangeListener mSeekListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    long duration;
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        show(3600000);
        duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
    }
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar, int progress, boolean fromtouch) {
        if (fromtouch) {
            mDragging = true;
            duration = mPlayer.getDuration();
            long newposition = (duration * progress) / 1000L;
            mPlayer.seekTo( (int) newposition);
            if (mCurrentTime != null)
                mCurrentTime.setText(stringForTime( (int) newposition));
        }
    }
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar) {
        mDragging = false;
        setProgress();
        updatePausePlay();
        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

@Override
public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    if (mPauseButton != null) {
        mPauseButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mFfwdButton != null) {
        mFfwdButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mRewButton != null) {
        mRewButton.setEnabled(enabled);
    }
    if (mNextButton != null) {
        mNextButton.setEnabled(enabled && mNextListener != null);
    }
    if (mPrevButton != null) {
        mPrevButton.setEnabled(enabled && mPrevListener != null);
    }
    if (mProgress != null) {
        mProgress.setEnabled(enabled);
    }

    super.setEnabled(enabled);
}

private View.OnClickListener mRewListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        pos -= 5000; // milliseconds
        mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
        setProgress();

        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener mFfwdListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        pos += 15000; // milliseconds
        mPlayer.seekTo(pos);
        setProgress();

        show(sDefaultTimeout);
    }
};

private void installPrevNextListeners() {
    if (mNextButton != null) {
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(mNextListener);
        mNextButton.setEnabled(mNextListener != null);
    }

    if (mPrevButton != null) {
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(mPrevListener);
        mPrevButton.setEnabled(mPrevListener != null);
    }
}

public void setPrevNextListeners(View.OnClickListener next, View.OnClickListener prev) {
    mNextListener = next;
    mPrevListener = prev;
    mListenersSet = true;

    if (mRoot != null) {
        installPrevNextListeners();

        if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml) {
            mNextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml) {
            mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}

public interface MediaPlayerControl {
    void    start();
    void    pause();
    int     getDuration();
    int     getCurrentPosition();
    void    seekTo(int pos);
    boolean isPlaying();
    int     getBufferPercentage();
};
```

}

and I am getting error at "Policy manager" at initfloatwindow method and I have imported import com.android.internal.policy.PolicyManager

```
 private void initFloatingWindow() {
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService("window");
   mWindow = PolicyManager.makeNewWindow(mContext);//I got error here
    mWindow.setWindowManager(mWindowManager, null, null);
    mWindow.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mDecor = mWindow.getDecorView();
    mDecor.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    mWindow.setContentView(this);
    mWindow.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

    // While the media controller is up, the volume control keys should
    // affect the media stream type
    mWindow.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
    requestFocus();
}
```

Please anyone can help me please.Thanks in advance

Comment: hello.. how did you finally resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`PolicyManager` is an internal class, not in puplic API so you cannot use it.